# Query array or create a temp DB

Tags: sql, vb.net, arrays

Is there any way to query an array of mine in VB.net? I just need something temporary in order to query it for a report but I do not want to make an external database just for something that's going to be temp. I just need to be able to say `select * from tempTable` etc etc.

Any help or links would be great!

Comment: As suggested below, look into LINQ. There are a lot of great applications for it. Really nifty tool to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ

```
Dim Report_Array As List(Of clsReport) = Get_Report_List


Dim Selected_Report As List(Of clsReport) = (From R As clsReport In Report_Array
                                             WHERE R.ReportName = 'ABC')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to query array in Vb.Net. Please see the article [Using LINQ to Objects in Visual Basic](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26652/Using-LINQ-to-Objects-in-Visual-Basic)

```
Dim Birds() As String = {"Indigo Bunting", "Rose Breasted Grosbeak", _ 
                             "Robin", "House Finch", "Gold Finch", _
                             "Ruby Throated Hummingbird", _
                             "Rufous Hummingbird", "Downy Woodpecker"}




Dim list = From b In Birds _
           Where b.StartsWith("R") _
           Select b
```